# Mysql IN query instead of multiple AND conditon

Tags: php, mysql

I have three mysql tables, category,students and student_category. for each student there is 1 or more category will be there and it is stored in student_category as follows.

```
1)   Categgory

   ----------------------------
    id      |  category_name
   ---------------------------
    1       |   A
    2       |   B
    3       |   C
    4       |   D


2)   Students

--------------------------
  id    |   name   
--------------------------
  1     | John
  2     | Kumar
  3     | Ashok
  4     | Jorge
  5     | Suku
 -------------------------


2)  student_category

  -----------------------------------------
    id    |   student_id    |  category_id
   -----------------------------------------
    1     |     1           |    2
    2     |     1           |    4
    3     |     2           |    3
    4     |     2           |    1
    5     |     3           |    2
 ------------------------------------------
```

**I need to select students which contain category_id 2 and 4.**

i used query as follows but it return either students contain category 2 or category 4.

```
   select A.name from students A, student_category B where A.id=B.student_id
   and B.category_id IN (2,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t3.name
FROM students t1
INNER JOIN student_category t2
    ON t1.id = t2.student_id
INNER JOIN students t3
    ON t1.id = t3.id
WHERE t2.category_id IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.category_id) = 2
```

**Explanation:**

This query joins together the `students` and `student_category` tables, and then removes all records which are not category 2 or 4.  This means that each student would then only have category 2 and 4 records associated with him.  The `HAVING` clause then restricts further by requiring that a student have *two* distinct categories, which if true must mean that the student has *both* category 2 and 4.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: `DISTINCT` may be omitted under the assumption that `<student_id, category_id>` pair is unique.

Comment: @1000111 Yes, I know this.  But I wanted to make sure that my answer would still run in the presence of such duplicates.

Comment: I got it. You are thinking about possibilities. But you can add that as a note in the answer. That will make the answer comprehensive.

Comment: it is working, thanks,  But is there any simple query work like  'IN'

Comment: The problem with `IN` is that is ORs together the conditions, but you need to AND them together.  I could give an alternative to this answer, but it would also be more complex than just using `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select name from Students where id in (select student_id from student_category where category_id in (2,4))
```

your query is fine btw.

Comment: His query isn't fine, and yours also will give the wrong results (see here: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/667cb/3)).  The problem is that you are identifying students who are in category 2 _or_ 4, but not necessarily both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select 
    s.name
from
    Students s,
    Categgory c,
    student_category sc
where
    sc.student_id = s.id
        and sc.category_id = c.id
        and c.id = 2
        and c.id = 4
```

You can check it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96d2e7/1). 
Have to take `distinct` student name as it will repeat if a student falls in more than one category.

Comment: His query isn't fine, and yours also will give the wrong results. The problem is that you are identifying students who are in category 2 or 4, but not necessarily both